# Reading useful data from barcode input

Tags: lpc, hid, barcode

I have interfaced a HID bar-code scanner with LPC2468. It is sending data when i scan a bar-code, it sends a lot of bytes when i make a scan, how can i know out of these bytes which are the bytes corresponding to the scanned bar-code.

For eg:If i scan a bar-code having value 2M12264185 it send following data

```
 1: Input Report:
    2: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    3: Input Report: 0, 0, 1F, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    4: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    5: Input Report: 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    6: Input Report: 2, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    7: Input Report: 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    8: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    9: Input Report: 0, 0, 1E, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    10: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    11: Input Report: 0, 0, 1F, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    12: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    13: Input Report: 0, 0, 1F, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    14: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    15: Input Report: 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    16: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    17: Input Report: 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    18: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    19: Input Report: 0, 0, 1E, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    20: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    21: Input Report: 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    22: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    23: Input Report: 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    24: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    25: Input Report: 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    26: Input Report: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

How to distinguish data bytes from other bytes.

Comment: That information should be available in the datasheet/user manual of the HID bar-code scanner. Do you have that?

Comment: @Gustavo Litovsky yes i have but m not able to find some useful information in it. here is the link http://www.posmicro.com/downloads/eclipse5145_ds_reva_0510_en.pdf

Comment: Does it operate like a keyboard when attached to a PC? If so maybe try search on "hid scan codes" or refer to the HID docs on the various codes for a keyboard. I just did a search and check the following, it seems to line up: http://www.mindrunway.ru/IgorPlHex/USBKeyScan.pdf

Comment: This website seems to include related software:
http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-AP/Pages/Product.aspx?category=hand-held-barcode-scanner&cat=HSM&pid=5145

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I'm not going to guess what every field is, your barcode scanner is emulating a USB HID keyboard. Each line with non-zero fields indicates a key-press, and all zeros indicates no key presses.

The third field is the USB HID key code. See [this link from the USB group](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/Hut1_11.pdf), starting with page 53. Note that the USB HID codes do not align with ASCII or other barcode languages. Checking the key codes versus what you say the barcode *should* be gives a 1:1 match.

The second field appears to be a modifier column, when it is equal to `2` the 'Shift' key is depressed. That would make your "input report 5-7" look like this:

```
4: 
5: <Shift>
6: <Shift> <M>
7: <Shift>
8:
```